# dev_appserver.py opens then immediately closes Google Cloud App Engine

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine

I'm following this guide to set up and test Google Cloud SDK app engine: [Installing App Engine with GCloud](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byu3UemwRffDbjd0SkdvajhIRW8/view)

I follow the guide until the "Your first App Engine webapp" section. At the end it says to run "dev_appserver.py ." I run this which prompts me to select a program to open the file. I pick python.exe in my python27 folder. a cmd prompt for python pops ups displays a ton of text then disappears unfortunately the box closes the instant the text appears so I cannot read it. If I go to the next step and open "http://localhost:8080/" it will not load. I assume because the python prompt is closing itself.

I am running python 2.7, I followed the instructions precisely, I tried reinstalling everything, shutting down computer, and going through it step by step again and I get the same problem.

What is causing this auto closing problem?

EDIT: It works if I run, in the GCloud SDK Shell: "python "C:\Users\ pathfile to dev_appserver.py..." instead of going directly to the directory running the .py file and choosing python. Its a way to do it, but not exactly user friendly to type out 8 folder directories.

Comment: Make sure you execute the cmd in an already open terminal, to not have a new ephemeral one being started for it - this should allow you to see the messages being displayed even after the program ends.

Comment: How do I stop it from opening a new cli when I run dev_appserver.py?

Comment: Don't use the `run cmd` facility, instead open a terminal (it used to be in accessories) and type the command at the command prompt in that terminal window.

Comment: I'm using the Cloud SDK Shell. I don't see terminal in windows 10 and google doesn't show it exists either.

Comment: Launch The Command Prompt From The Run Window. One of the quickest ways to launch the Command Prompt is to use the Run window (press Win+R on your keyboard to open it). Then, type cmd or cmd.exe and press Enter or click/tap OK.Jun 25, 2015

Comment: This manual way of executing the server is just to find out why it's exiting prematurely, after fixing that it's probably OK to run it the usual way. BTW - try using the TAB key when typing dir/filenames, it *might* help with auto-completion.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The solution below works for me. On windows command prompt write the following commands:

```
1 - cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\bin 
2 - python dev_appserver.py "C:\path\of\your\project"
```